# How to check current user permissions (SPFx)

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

How can I check the site permissions of the current user using the SharePoint Framework? How would I go about recreating the following:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();

var ob = new SP.BasePermissions();
ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.addAndCustomizePages)

var per = web.doesUserHavePermissions(ob)
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){ 
         alert(per.get_value()); // true if user has permission 
        },
     function(a,b){
         alert ("Something wrong");
 }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of this comes along for free.  The current list item is

```
this.context.pageContext.listItem.permissions
```

The current web is

```
this.context.pageContext.web.permissions
```

Comment: @PatMil_MSFT 
How to load SharePoint groups?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the typings for Microsoft AJAX and JSOM. To do that run the below commands:

```
tsd install microsoft.ajax

tsd install sharepoint
```

After that, you need to add the `config.json` you need to add below entries:

```
{
    "sp-init": {
     "path": "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/init.js",
     "globalName": "$_global_init"
    },
    "microsoft-ajax": {
     "path": "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js",
     "globalName": "Sys",
     "globalDependencies": [ "sp-init" ]
    },
    "sp-runtime": {
     "path": "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js",
     "globalName": "SP",
     "globalDependencies": [ "microsoft-ajax" ]
    },
    "sharepoint": {
     "path": "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.js",
     "globalName": "SP",
     "globalDependencies": [ "sp-runtime" ]
    }
}
```

Once you have added the entries, you need to add `require` statements for them in your webpart as below:

```
require('sp-init');
require('microsoft-ajax');
require('sp-runtime');
require('sharepoint');
```

After that, inside your render method , you can use that JSOM code that you posted above.

Comment: Please, don't give advise to use `tsd`. `tsd` is a deprecated tool long long time ago. Today you need to use either ms types publisher aka `@types` or `typings` npm tool or both.

Comment: @SergeiSergeev - sure will keep this in mind :)  Also, you rock, your answers are a source of great inspiration to me and they keep me reminded of how little I know about the SP universe !!!

Comment: WOW! Thanks! Your help is also extremely valuable. You are the top by rating per month for several months! Keep your good work and thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use JSOM after importing it like @gautam-sheth specifies.

Or you can use the SharePoint REST interface at:

```
https://<site url>/_api/web/doesuserhavepermissions(@v)?@v={'High':'0', 'Low':'262144'}
```

The high and low values specified is for AddAndCustomizePages.

Comment: Where can I find the correct High and Low values for use with this service?

Comment: One source is [Understand SharePoint Permissions - Part 1. SPBasePermissions in Hex, Decimal and Binary - The Basics](http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Understand-SharePoint-Permissions-Part-1-SPBasePermissions-in-Hex2c-Decimal-and-Binary-The-Basics.aspx), High should be the value of the high 16 bits and Low value of the low 16 bits

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I loaded JSOM but couldn't do it from the config.json because I needed a solution that would run from any tenant using relative paths to the external libraries.

I used the web part to load a js file containing the following code. I don't know if this is the best answer, but it worked.

```
requirejs.config({ enforceDefine: false });

var requireQueue = function (modules, callback) {
    function load(queue, results) {
        if (queue.length) {
            require([queue.shift()], function (result) {
                results.push(result);
                load(queue, results);
            });
        } else {
            callback.apply(null, results);
        }
    }
    load(modules, []);
};

requireQueue([
    '/_layouts/15/init.js',
    '/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js',
    '/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js',
    '/_layouts/15/SP.js'
], function () {
    // JSOM is loaded
});
```